# Can't convert JSON to object

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

Json response looks like this:

```json
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "id": "4iQDR9r1Ch",
                "body": "test test",
                "da": "1601575850",
                "dm": "1601575850"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And my classes:

```kotlin
data class NotesListResponse(
    @SerializedName("status") val status: Int,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: List<List<NoteResponse>>)

data class NoteResponse(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
    @SerializedName("body") val body: String,
    @SerializedName("da") val da: String,
    @SerializedName("dm") val dm: String
)
```

Error message: `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 48 path $.data[0][0].body`

What's wrong? JSON is valid and classes were checked for correctness

Comment: Do you have access to the `Gson` class, e.g., `Gson gson = new Gson();`?

Comment: @RossSheppard yes, other conversions (with another json and types) work perfectly

Comment: Have you tried putting `Gson` in `lenient` mode? This may help see whether there are characters within the response that `Gson` just doesn't like. I added an answer but let me know if that doesn't work!

Comment: I just used that and it worked, are you sure the JSON you are getting is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following if you have access to the `Gson` class. The `lenient` mode may allow you to see if it works and there are characters that the non-`lenient` mode can't parse.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(<insert response>));
reader.setLenient(true);
```